# Vertical swipe in hammer.js

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am using hammer.js to reset my timer when the user performs an action on their touch device. This works fine with tap, press and horizontal swipe, but how can I get it to recognise vertical swiping?

```
$(function () { 
    var page = document.getElementById("parent"); 

    Hammer(page).on("swipe", function () { 
        idleTime = 0; 
    }); 

    Hammer(page).on("tap", function () { 
        idleTime = 0; 
    }); 

    Hammer(page).on("press", function () { 
       idleTime = 0; 
    }); 

})
```

Answer (score 8):

Swipe is for all directions.

Use **swipeleft** and **swiperight** for horizontal swipe and **swipeup**, **swipedown** for vertical swipe.

```js
  $(function () { 
   var element = document.getElementById("parent"); 
   var mc = new Hammer(element);
   mc.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

   mc.on("swipeleft", function () { 
    alert('swipeleft');
   }); 
          
           mc.on("swiperight", function () { 
    alert('swiperight');
   });
   
   mc.on("swipeup", function () { 
    alert('swipeup');
   }); 
   
   mc.on("swipedown", function () { 
    alert('swipedown');
   });
          
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" style="width:100%;height:500px;background:#ff0000;"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried swipeup and swipedown and they don't work??

Comment: Yes, you need to activate vertical swipe as is it disabled by default `hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL });`. More : http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/

Comment: How would I implement that into my code in the question? Would I have to assign the page variable to it? (Sorry I'm new at this).

Comment: Thank you, that works great. The only problem is that it's not allowing me to scroll up or down when swiping over the parent div. The screen just stays still when swiping up or down over this particular div.

Comment: Using version 2.0.1 instead of 2.0.8 seems to have resolved the issue with the scrolling. Thank you so much for your help.